# Access control allow origin is always * when credentials is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cors, apollo-server

i am building a graphql api using `apollo-server-express`. I am using jwt and cookies for authentication so in my cors options `credentials` is set to true, the thing is, when `credentials` is set to true, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is always `*`, even if i set the `origin` in my cors options, it still is `*`.

here is my middleware:

```
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://studio.apollographql.com",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "2mb" }));
app.use(cookieParser());
```

To reproduce you need a graphql and express server.

```
// Initialize dotenv
dotenv.config();

// Get env variables
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Create express server
const app = express();

// Express server middleware
app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "https://studio.apollographql.com",
  })
);
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "2mb" }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Create new apollo server
const gqlServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: [typedefs],
  resolvers: { ...resolvers },
  context: ({ req, res }: ContextType) => {
    // const { isValid, userData } = verifyToken(req.cookies?.xToken);

    return {
      // isLoggedIn: isValid,
      // userData: userData,
      req,
      res,
    };
  },
});

(async () => {
  await gqlServer.start();

  gqlServer.applyMiddleware({ app });

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
  });
})();
```

Then you need to go on `localhost:5000/graphql`, tap `query your server`, and go to apollo. In apollo studio, on the top left, where your url is displayed (should be `localhost:5000`), there should be a little cog icon (settings icon), you can tap on that, then go to `include cookies` and set it on. Thats it, if you go in dev tools at the network tab, you'll see cors errors from your server `localhost:5000` ant the value of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is `*`. btw you need to set up some resolvers and type definitions.

## Update

I solved the problem, i needed to apply the cors middleware to my graphql server as well.

```
  gqlServer.applyMiddleware({
    app,
    cors: {
      origin: "https://studio.apollographql.com",
      credentials: true,
    },
  });
```

Comment: => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example